# How to redirect to denial access page when using role based access in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

What are all the ways we can redirect to a page in case of denial of access based on roles?

I can able to get the role based authorization working but I ended up the page redirected to login page always in case of no authorization for one particular role. Please help

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" 
   defaultUrl="Unauthorizedaccess.aspx"  protection="All" path="/"
   requireSSL="false"
   cookieless="UseUri" domain=""
   enableCrossAppRedirects="false" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880"></forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

```
<location path="ABC.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

I am not sure where I need to specify where to redirect in case of access denial. The default URL i specified not seems to be working

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect to other page according their roles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406519/redirect-to-other-page-according-their-roles)

Comment: I understand how to route based on roles from Codebase, I am asking how to specify the denial access page. In web.confing not in the codebase. Please advise

Comment: Its unclear what you ask. Its better to give a code example, where you have stack, what you did not understand or not find.

Comment: Have edited the question. Please let me know your comments.

Comment: AFAIK you'll always need some code, you can't redirect to different pages (instead of login.aspx) according to current logged-in user role.

Comment: what I am asking is, something like customErrors entry in web.config where we can route to some URL in case if the status code is 401 (unauthorized access). It didnt work either. I will try some other approach.